# Rails, devise y CanCanCan, error: uninitialized constant Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Tengo el siguiente problema y necesito ayuda

Tengo el controlador `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` #que hereda de Devise (necesito sobre escribir los métodos del controlador)

De que manera puedo usar: `load_and_authorize_resource` ?

Ya que al colocarlo y llamar a la acción new para que el administrador registre un usuario (solo lo puede hacer el administrador), me muestra lo siguiente:

`uninitialized constant Registration`

Y en `Ability.rb` `can :manage, Registration` #lo he colocado de todas las maneras posibles.

Necesito ayuda

Este es el stack completo del error:

> NameError - uninitialized constant Registration: activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in load_missing_constant'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:inconst_missing' activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in block in
>   constantize'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:inconstantize'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in constantize'
>   cancancan (2.0.0)
>   lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:156:inresource_class' cancancan
>   (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:192:in resource_base'
>   cancancan (2.0.0)
>   lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:80:inbuild_resource' cancancan
>   (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:61:in
>   load_resource_instance'   cancancan (2.0.0)
>   lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:35:inload_resource' cancancan
>   (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:12:in block in
>   add_before_action'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:inblock in make_lambda'
>   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in block in
>   halting'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:inblock in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in_run_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in
>   _run_process_action_callbacks'   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:inrun_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:inprocess_action' actionpack
>   (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in block in
>   process_action'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:inblock in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:ininstrument' actionpack
>   (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in
>   process_action'   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:inprocess_action'
>   activerecord (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:inprocess'
>   actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in process'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:indispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:inblock in
>   action' actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in dispatch'   actionpack
>   (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:inserve'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in serve' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:inblock in
>   serve' actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in
>   serve'   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:intraced_call' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:intraced_call'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:intraced_call' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:inblock in call' warden
>   (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in call'   newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in call'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in
>   call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in context'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:incall'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   activerecord (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:incall'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:incall'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:inblock in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in
>   _run_callbacks'   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in
>   run_callbacks'   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:incall' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   better_errors (2.1.1)
>   lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:inprotected_app_call' better_errors
>   (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in better_errors_call'
>   better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:incall'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:incall'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:inblock in call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in call'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in call'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:inblock in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:intagged' activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in tagged'   railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:incall' quiet_assets (1.1.0)
>   lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in call_with_quiet_assets'   newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in
>   call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in call'   newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in call'   newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in
>   call'   newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in call'   newrelic_rpm
>   (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:incall'
>   railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in call'   railties (4.2.1)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:164:incall' newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in call' 
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:incall' thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in block in pre_process'   thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:84:inpre_process' thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in process'   thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/connection.rb:39:inreceive_data' eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
>   lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in run'   thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:instart' thin (1.7.0)
>   lib/thin/server.rb:162:in start'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:inrun' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/server.rb:286:in start'   railties (4.2.1)
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:instart' railties (4.2.1)
>   lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in block in server'   railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:inserver' railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in run_command!'
>   railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in' bin/rails:9:in '   spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:incall'
>   spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in call'   spring
>   (1.7.2) lib/spring/client.rb:30:inrun' spring (1.7.2) bin/spring:49:in
>   '   spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in'
>   bin/spring:13:in '   bin/rails:3:in'

Comment: Tiene creado el archivo de la clase (modelo no controlador) `Registration`?

Comment: No lo tengo creado por que es de devise el modelo es Usuario.rb, leyendo por ahí cuando el modelo es distinto colocas, en load_and_authorize_resource class:  "RegistrationsController"
pero no funciona

Comment: No recuerdo haber visto que era posible con controladores, a la rápida encontré lo que mencionas pero se utiliza para cambiar el nombre de la clase en casos donde el nombre del controlador no coincide con el del model ([link](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#custom-class))

Comment: Si es así, y lo use precisamente para eso por que el modelo se llama Usuario y el controlador Registrations, pero sigo sin resolver el problema

Comment: Probaste con lo siguiente: en `Ability.rb` colocar `can :manage, User` ? y en el controlador `RegistrationsController` colocar `load_and_authorize_resource class: "User"`

Comment: Si ya lo probe así, y me dispara la excepción que tengo en ApplicationController 
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, alert: 'No tiene autorización para acceder' }
        format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
  end